# Yamabe Positive iff Admits Metric of Positive Scalar Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I'm trying to prove that the Yamabe invariant of a compact manifold, that is the sigma constant, is positive iff $M$ admits a metric of positive scalar curvature. I will use $$Y_{[g]} = \underset{g \in [g]}{\inf} \mathcal{E}(g)$$ to be the Yamabe constant with

$$\mathcal{E}(g) = {\frac{{\int_{M}S_g \Omega}}{\left({\int_{M} \Omega}\right)^{{\frac{n-2}{n}}}}}$$

One direction is straightforward. That is, assume $\sigma(M) > 0$, then there exists some conformal class [g] such that $Y_{[g]} > 0$. Then by the Yamabe problem there exists a metric $\tilde{g} \in [g]$ such that $(M,\tilde{g})$ has constant positive scalar curvature.

I'm struggling with the other direction. Suppose $M$ admits a metric of positive scalar curvature $g_0$, say. We want to show that $$\sigma(M) = \underset{[g]\in \mathcal{C}_M }{\sup} Y_{[g]} > 0$$ with $\mathcal{C}_{M}$ being the set of conformal classes on $M$.

So we just need to show there exists a conformal class giving a positive Yamabe constant. Given the information we have I would imagine that this supremum is achieved by $Y_{[g_0]}$. But I'm having trouble showing that this is positive. What's stopping there being some other metric, say $\tilde{g_0} \in [g_0]$ such that $\mathcal{E}(\tilde{g_0}) \leq 0$ thus giving a non-positive value for $Y_{[g_0]}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g$ be a metric of positive scalar curvature.  We will show that $Y_{[g]}>0$.  Note that if $c>0$ is a constant, then $S_{cg}=c^{-1}S_g$, so there is no loss in generality in assuming that $0<\inf S \leq \frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}$.

Let $\hat g\in[g]$.  Write $\hat g = u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g$ for some positive function $u$.  Then
$$ \tag{$\dagger$} \int S_{\hat g}\Omega_{\hat g} = \int \left( \frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}\lvert\nabla u\rvert_g^2 + S_gu^2 \right)\Omega_g \geq (\inf S_g) \lVert u\rVert_{1,2}^2 , $$
where $\lVert u\rVert_{1,2}^2$ is the $W^{1,2}(M^n)$-norm of $u$.  (The first equality follows from the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Scalar_curvature_2) for $S_{\hat g}$ in terms of $g$ and $u$.)  Note that $\inf S_g>0$ by assumption.  Now, the [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) of the embedding $W^{1,2}(M^n)\subset L^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}(M^n)$ implies that there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$ \tag{$\ddagger$} \lVert w\rVert_{\frac{2n}{n-2}} \leq C\lVert w\rVert_{1,2} $$
for all $w\in W^{1,2}(M^n)$.  Combining ($\dagger$) and ($\ddagger$) implies that
$$ \int S_{\hat g}\Omega_{\hat g} \geq C^\prime \lVert u\rVert_{\frac{2n}{n-2}}^2 = C^\prime\left( \int \Omega_{\hat g} \right)^{\frac{n-2}{n}} , $$
where $C^\prime>0$ is determined by $\inf S$ and $C$; and the last equality is just the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Volume_form) for $\Omega_{\hat g}$ in terms of $\Omega_g$.  This last display proves that $Y_{[g]}>0$.

Comment: Great answer - thank you. Just a few follow up questions. I have no experience of functional analysis on Riemannian manifolds so I'm wondering what allows us to generalise the Sobolev embedding theorem from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to also work on $M$?

Comment: In the linked page on Sobolev embedding, I see we're in the second case because we are embedding $W^{1,2}(M^n)$ into $L^{2^*}(M^n)$ (ie. $k=1$ and $l=0$). However this assumes $M^n = \mathbb{R}^n$. The Riemannian generalisation appears to be the Kondrachov embedding theorem given further down the page which says nothing about the second case, for which $k = 1$ and $l=0$. Kondrachov requires an inequality $\frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n} < \frac{1}{q} - \frac{l}{n}$ instead of an equality, and thus appears to no longer hold (since we have $p=2, k=1, q=\frac{np}{n-2},  l=0$ which gives equality here)

Comment: Then in $\dagger$ let $a= 4\frac{n-1}{n-2}$ for brevity. I can't understand the final inequality. We obviously have $\int \left( a\lvert\nabla u\rvert_g^2 + S_gu^2 \right)\Omega_g \geq \int \left(a\lvert\nabla u\rvert_g^2 + (\inf S_g)u^2 \right)\Omega_g$. But if, say $\inf S_g > a$ then $\int \left(a\lvert\nabla u\rvert_g^2 + (\inf S_g)u^2 \right)\Omega_g \ngeq \int \left((\inf S_g)\lvert\nabla u\rvert_g^2 + (\inf S_g)u^2 \right)\Omega_g = \inf(S_g){\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert}_{1,2}^2$? I'm wondering how you get the final inequality?

Comment: @JMill You can extend the Sobolev embedding theorem to $M$ by a standard partition of unity argument.  Roughly the idea goes as follows: Take a finite cover $\{ U_\alpha \}$ of $M$ (recall $M$ is compact) and a partition of unity $\{ \eta_\alpha \}$ subordinate to the cover.  Given a function $u$ on $M$, set $u_\alpha = \eta_\alpha u$, so that $u=\sum u_\alpha$ and each $u_\alpha$ --- which is supported in $U_\alpha$ --- can be regarded as a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Apply the $\mathbb{R}^n$ Sobolev inequality to each $u_\alpha$ and then add everything up.

Comment: @JMill Also, this argument is not using the Kondrachev theorem (which asserts compactness of the embedding), just the Sobolev theorem (which only asserts continuity of the embedding, or equivalently, that the inclusion map is bounded).  Finally, I had originally written the argument assuming $\inf S\leq a$; this can be arranged by scaling, for example, as done in the edit.